# Change/replace the value of a variable dynamically- oracle

Tags: sql, oracle, stored-procedures

I have set of sql statements (create table, views, sequences), Where my schema name changes all the time and rest of the sql be the same. 
Even in schema name a part of it has to change, for example:
I have a `schema` name `ABC_XYZ`, i would like to change this schema name to `ABC_DEF_XYZ`. 
For this i tried to insert a variable in the schema name like `ABC_&var1_XYZ`. If i pass the variable in the schema name as shown here (`ABC_&var1_XYZ`) and pass the value to the variable, It ask me to declare the vaue of the variable.
I have given the error and the code i use below:

```
Error report -
ORA-06550: line 5, column 52:
PLS-00201: identifier 'REL4' must be declared
ORA-06550: line 5, column 1:
PL/SQL: Statement ignored
ORA-06550: line 7, column 51:
PLS-00201: identifier 'REL4' must be declared
```

here is my create statement:

```
   set echo off
set verify off
undefine  mySchemaPart
declare 
    vSQL      varchar2(32767);
begin

vSQL:= 'begin EXECUTE IMMEDIATE alter table ABC_'||&&mySchemaPart||'_OWNER.TEST drop constraint EMPLOYEE_ID_FK; EXCEPTION when others then if (SQLCODE != -02443 and SQLCODE != -942) then RAISE; end if; end';
 execute immediate vSQL;
vSQL:= 'begin EXECUTE IMMEDIATE drop table ABC_'||&mySchemaPart||'_OWNER.TEST cascade constraints PURGE; EXCEPTION when others then if SQLCODE != -942 then RAISE; end if; end';
 execute immediate vSQL;
vSQL:= 'create table ABC_'||&mySchemaPart||'OWNER.TEST 
(
   EMPLOYEE_ID     NUMBER(19)           not null,
   LAST_UPDT_DT         DATE                 not null,
   )';
    execute immediate vSQL;
vSQL:= 'CREATE OR REPLACE SYNONYM ABC_USER.TEST FOR ABC_'||&mySchemaPart||'OWNER.TEST';
 execute immediate vSQL;
vSQL:= 'begin EXECUTE IMMEDIATE alter table ABC_'||&mySchemaPart||'OWNER.TEST
   add constraint EMPLOYEE_ID_FK foreign key (EMPLOYEE_ID)
      references ABC_OWNER.GDSD (EMPLOYEE_ID); EXCEPTION when others then if (SQLCODE != -02443 and SQLCODE != -02275) then RAISE; end if; end';
 execute immediate vSQL;
end;
/
```

Is there any other way i can try to insert my value in this schema.

Comment: Please post a relevant part of your code

Comment: how about using `execute immediate` ?

Comment: You cannot simply pass the variable while creating  a table. You need to use a PLSQL block if you want to make it parameterised. See examples below

Comment: Hi @XING, I tried doing the way you suggested but when i enter the value it throws an error:ORA-06550: line 6, column 31:
PLS-00201: identifier 'REL4' must be declared
ORA-06550: line 6, column 1:
PL/SQL: Statement ignored. and My SQL is 
declare
var varchar2(100);
begin
var:='create table ABC_'||&var1||'_OWNER.TEST 
(   EMPLOYEE_ID              NUMBER               not null,
   EMPNAME             VARCHAR2(35)         not null,
   constraint TEST_PK_ primary key (EMPLOYEE_ID)
) ;
dbms_output.put_line(var);
 execute immediate var;
end;  Please suggest

Comment: What you tried and it didnt work..!!! I can see you posted below that it worked.

Comment: @XING, Yes unfortunately it worked for that example but didn't work for my code. When i pass the value to the dynamic variable, it throws an error saying that the value must be declared. I have modified the code in the actual question with what i tried. Could you please help me :(

Comment: @bin..You must check if whatever you are doing is valid before commenting the solution given doesnot work. You code is not working coz it  has errors and obviously it shouldnot work. Check the updated answer as per your need. I tested it and its wrking fine,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Pass it as `'ABC_||'&var1||'_XYZ'`

An example of insert statement;

```
insert into test (a) 
select 'ABC_'||&var1||'_XYZ' from dual ;
```

On execution it will ask for prompt.

As a block you can use this:

```
declare

var varchar2(100);
begin

var:='create table  ABC_'||&var1||'_XYZ.tablnam(a number)'; --add your columns

dbms_output.put_line(var);

 execute immediate var;

end;
```

As per @bin request his/her statments:

```
declare

var varchar2(500);
begin

var:='create table ABC_'||&var||'_OWNER.TEST(EMPLOYEE_ID  NUMBER(19) not null, LAST_UPDT_DT  DATE  not null )';

--Table Created
dbms_output.put_line(var);
execute immediate var;

var:='alter table ABC_'||&var1||'_OWNER.TEST add constraint EMPLOYEE_ID_FK foreign key (EMPLOYEE_ID) references ABC_OWNER.GDSD(EMPLOYEE_ID)';

--Constraint Added
dbms_output.put_line(var);
execute immediate var;


var:='CREATE OR REPLACE SYNONYM ABC_USER.TEST FOR ABC_'||&var1||'_OWNER.TEST';

--Synonym  Created
dbms_output.put_line(var);
execute immediate var;


var:='alter table ABC_'||&var1||'_OWNER.TEST drop constraint EMPLOYEE_ID_FK';

--Constraint Dropped
dbms_output.put_line(var);
execute immediate var;


var:='drop table ABC_'||&var1||'_OWNER.TEST cascade constraints PURGE';

--Table Dropped
dbms_output.put_line(var);
execute immediate var;


Exception
 WHEN others then 
 dbms_output.put_line('Error--'||sqlerrm||'-'||sqlcode); 

end;
```

Output:

```
SQL> declare
     var varchar2(100);
     begin
     var:='create table  ABC_'||&var1||'OWNER.TEST(EMPLOYEE_ID  NUMBER(19) not null, LAST_UPDT_DT  DATE  not null )';
 ' 
 '
 '
dbms_output.put_line(var);

 execute immediate var;

end;

Enter value for var1: 'REL4'

    create table ABC_REL4_OWNER.TEST(EMPLOYEE_ID  NUMBER(19) not null, LAST_UPDT_DT  DATE  not null )
    Table created.

    alter table ABC_REL4_OWNER.TEST add constraint EMPLOYEE_ID_FK foreign key (EMPLOYEE_ID) references ABC_OWNER.GDSD(EMPLOYEE_ID)
     Table altered.

    CREATE OR REPLACE SYNONYM ABC_USER.TEST FOR ABC_REL4_OWNER.TEST
     Synonym created.

    alter table ABC_REL4_OWNER.TEST drop constraint EMPLOYEE_ID_FK
     Table altered.

    drop table ABC_REL4_OWNER.TEST cascade constraints PURGE
     Table dropped.
```

Comment: Hi XING, Am using this schema name while creating tables ex: Create table abc_&var1_xyz.tablename. I also tried the way you suggested above but it throws an error :ORA-06550: line 2, column 39:
PLS-00103: Encountered the symbol "RDS_" when expecting one of the following:

   * & = - + ; < / > at in is mod remainder not rem return
   returning <an exponent (**)> <> or != or ~= >= <= <> and or
   like like2 like4 likec between into using || multiset bulk
   member submultiset
06550. 00000 -  "line %s, column %s:\n%s"
*Cause:    Usually a PL/SQL compilation error.
*Action:

Comment: post your create statement;

Comment: Please do not post code in comments, edit your question instead

Comment: @XING, The problem is it works with numbers like 657 but is failing with REL4 value. If i pass rel4 it asks me to  declare rel4

Comment: You must use single quotes while inputting the value when you are passing a string. When prompt give input as 'REL4' and see.

Comment: we just have to put the value in ''. it worked. Thank you @XING

Answer (score 1):

You can use dynamic SQL to handle a varying schema in your DDL; for example:

```
accept mySchemaPart PROMPT "Schema part: "
declare
    vMySchema varchar2(30) := 'ABC_' || '&mySchemaPart' || '_XYZ';
    vSQL      varchar2(32767);
begin
   vSQL := 'create table ' || vMySchema || '.tableName (...)';
   execute immediate vSQL;
end;
/
```

Comment: Aleksej, My requirement was to change the part of the schema name, i shouldn't be replacing the whole schema name :(